# Why does DataGrid call collection's IndexOf passing the object of type ItemcControl.ItemInfo?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid, inotifycollectionchanged

I created `SelectionHelper` for `DataGrid` which allows binding for selected items in both directions.
In this helper I call `ScrollIntoView` for the first selected item, when selection changes from viewmodel. The call successfully returns. But later somewhere in UI's message queue something happens and IndexOf for my collection is called.
I suspect it to be async because of the UI virtualization. `DataGrid` is definitely whants to know item's index. But what I cannot understand why it puts `ItemsControl.ItemInfo` instead of item.
Is this a bug or undocumented feature?

My collection implements these interfaces: `IList<T>`, `IList`, `INotifyCollectionChanged`

and here is the code of `IndexOf`:

```
public int IndexOf(object value)
        {
            if ((value != null && !(value is T))
                || (value == null && typeof(T).IsValueType))
                throw new ArgumentException(WrongTypeMessage, "value");

            return IndexOf((T)value);
        }
```

And it throws exception as expected =)

**Update**

Yes, my guess was right. Here's the code for DataGrid's `ScrollIntoView`

```
public void ScrollIntoView(object item)
    {
      if (item == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
      this.ScrollIntoView(this.NewItemInfo(item, (DependencyObject) null, -1));
    }

    internal void ScrollIntoView(ItemsControl.ItemInfo info)
    {
      if (this.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
        this.OnBringItemIntoView(info);
      else
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, (Delegate) new DispatcherOperationCallback(((ItemsControl) this).OnBringItemIntoView), (object) info);
    }
```

**Update**
Problem is fixed in this [update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2750149/en-us)

Comment: May be, you can add your explanation as answer, and except your own answer.

Comment: I'm not seeing the IndexOf in the 'explanation part'.

Comment: @Henk See my answer please. This call is just a little deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, probably I've found the reason:

Here's the code of DataGrid.ScrollIntoView (decompiled by Resharper)

```
internal void ScrollIntoView(ItemsControl.ItemInfo info)
    {
     if (this.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
        this.OnBringItemIntoView(info);
     else
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, (Delegate) new DispatcherOperationCallback(((ItemsControl) this).OnBringItemIntoView), (object) info);
    }
```

Here they cast `info` to the object type. Whell, the problem is really that `DispatcherOperationCallback` expects `object`.
But `ItemsControl` has two overloads for `OnBringItemIntoView`:
one for `ItemsControl.ItemInfo` and the second for `object` type.

```
internal object OnBringItemIntoView(ItemsControl.ItemInfo info)
    {
      FrameworkElement frameworkElement = info.Container as FrameworkElement;
      if (frameworkElement != null)
        frameworkElement.BringIntoView();
      else if ((info = this.LeaseItemInfo(info, true)).Index >= 0)
      {
        VirtualizingPanel virtualizingPanel = this.ItemsHost as VirtualizingPanel;
        if (virtualizingPanel != null)
          virtualizingPanel.BringIndexIntoView(info.Index);
      }
      return (object) null;
    }

internal object OnBringItemIntoView(object arg)
    {
     return this.OnBringItemIntoView(this.NewItemInfo(arg, (DependencyObject) null, -1));
    }
```

Guess, which one is selected? ;-)
So they get `ItemInfo` wrapped in `ItemInfo`. That's why `this.LeaseItemInfo(info, true)` iside

```
internal object OnBringItemIntoView(ItemsControl.ItemInfo info)
    {
      FrameworkElement frameworkElement = info.Container as FrameworkElement;
      if (frameworkElement != null)
        frameworkElement.BringIntoView();
      else if ((info = this.LeaseItemInfo(info, true)).Index >= 0)
      {
        VirtualizingPanel virtualizingPanel = this.ItemsHost as VirtualizingPanel;
        if (virtualizingPanel != null)
          virtualizingPanel.BringIndexIntoView(info.Index);
      }
      return (object) null;
    }
```

recieves incorrect item and calls `IndexOf` with wrong value:

```
 internal ItemsControl.ItemInfo LeaseItemInfo(ItemsControl.ItemInfo info, bool ensureIndex = false)
    {
      if (info.Index < 0)
      {
        info = this.NewItemInfo(info.Item, (DependencyObject) null, -1);
        if (ensureIndex && info.Index < 0)
          info.Index = this.Items.IndexOf(info.Item);
      }
      return info;
    }
```

But this should break `ScrollIntoView` for all the cases when containers were not generated. The simple workaround is to call `ScrollIntoView` via `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`

I'll wait for the [answer](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776253/itemscontrol-calls-indexof-method-of-bound-collection-passing-internal-class-itemscontrol-iteminfo) of MS.

Comment: `info.Item` should be your type, not ItemInfo. I don't see an explanation here.

Comment: Ok. If you have two overloads of the method which one is selected as the delegate param?

Comment: Yes, you might have something here. I had to read it again. That BeginInvoke call is suspect at the least.